# XAMPP VirtualHosts Access From Mobile Device

Tags: xampp, localhost, virtualhost

Could you please help me to access XAMPP localhost sites from a mobile device (either from home network or from internet)

I am using multiple virtual hosts to access all sites using a short link for each. Please see the configuration of virtual hosts below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite
    ServerAlias mysite
    DocumentRoot "F:/Drive/Dev/mysite"  
    <Directory "F:/Drive/Dev/mysite">    
        AllowOverride All    
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        Require all granted
    </Directory>  
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite2
    ServerAlias mysite2
    DocumentRoot "F:/Drive/Dev/mysite2"  
    <Directory "F:/Drive/Dev/mysite2">    
        AllowOverride All    
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        Require all granted
    </Directory>  
</VirtualHost>
```

and the host file:

```
127.0.0.1 mysite
127.0.0.1 mysite2
```

I have tried several suggestion found here, but non of them helped...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngrok creates a secure public URL (https://yourapp.ngrok.io) to a local webserver on your machine

test mobile apps against a development backend running on your machine.

https://ngrok.com/